# How to find and replace a string by increasing its numerical part?

Tags: command-line, sed, awk

My input file is,

```
ami21 ami65
ami67 ami66
ami88 ami76 ami29
ami55 
ami54
ami32
```

Using a single command line I need the output as,

```
ami22 ami66
ami68 ami67
ami89 ami77 ami30
ami56
ami55
ami33
```

I used the command

```
awk -vRS=ami '{$0=$0+1;ORS=RT}++n' inputfile > outputfile
```

but I got the outputfile as `ami21ami65ami67ami66ami88ami76ami29ami55ami54ami32`

i.e. all strings are written in same line and without space. Could anyone suggext me some better command line.

Comment: [Increment every number in a string](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/38033/increment-every-number-in-a-string) on [codegolf.stackexchange.com](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It might be easier to use `perl` for this:

```
$ perl -pe 's/(\d+)/$1+1/eg' foo
ami22 ami66
ami68 ami67
ami89 ami77 ami30
ami56 
ami55
ami33
```

- `-pe`: loop through the file, line by line, printing each line after evaluating the expression
- `s/(\d+)/$1+1/e`: match a number (`\d+`), and replace it with its increment (`$1+1`), with `e` being used to tell Perl to evaluate the replacement.

With `awk`, you have to include the whitespace in the record separator:

```
$ awk -v RS='[[:space:]]*ami[[:space:]]*' '$0{$0++;}{ORS=RT}1' foo
ami22 ami66
ami68 ami67
ami89 ami77 ami30
ami56 
ami55
ami33
```

Comment: I was about to propose the same perl code :). You need to add /g to your regexp though as only the first match is incremented.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the excellent answer provided by "muru" if you want to try something different, here is a Pythonic way:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import re
with open('file_name.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        final_list = ['ami' + str(int(value) + 1) for value in re.findall('\d+', line)]
        print ' '.join(final_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another python solution through `re.sub`.

```
$ python3 -c 'import re, sys
with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
    for line in f:
        print(re.sub(r"\d+", lambda x: str(int(x.group())+1), line), end="")' file
ami22 ami66
ami68 ami67
ami89 ami77 ami30
ami56 
ami55
ami33
```